# Set naming style to camelCase for private methods via .editorconfig

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

In my solution folder, I have private methods with signatures like the following:

```csharp
private void fooBar() { }
```

Visual Studio provides a naming suggestion to name the method in Pascal case: `FooBar` instead of `fooBar`. I am trying to disable the suggestion via an `.editorconfig` in the root of the solution, using the following lines:

```ini
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_method_should_be_camel_case.applicable_kinds = method
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_method_should_be_camel_case.applicable_accessibilities = private

dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.capitalization = camel_case

dotnet_naming_rule.private_method_should_be_camel_case.style = camel_case
```

However, Visual Studio still shows the suggestion even after I've closed and reopened the solution.

[image]

How can I get Visual Studio to apply these rules/styles?

---

For reference, I'm including the entire `.editorconfig` file here:

```ini
[*.{cs,vb}]
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = true

dotnet_separate_import_directive_groups = false
dotnet_sort_system_directives_first = false

dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:suggestion

dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true:suggestion

dotnet_style_parentheses_in_arithmetic_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary:silent
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary:silent
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_operators = never_if_unnecessary:silent
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_relational_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary:silent

dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers = for_non_interface_members:silent

dotnet_style_coalesce_expression = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_collection_initializer = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_explicit_tuple_names = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_null_propagation = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_object_initializer = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_operator_placement_when_wrapping = end_of_line
dotnet_style_prefer_auto_properties = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_compound_assignment = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_assignment = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_return = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_anonymous_type_member_names = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_tuple_names = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_is_null_check_over_reference_equality_method = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_boolean_expressions = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_interpolation = true:suggestion

dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.symbols = interface
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.style = begins_with_i

dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = types
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = non_field_members
dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_kinds = interface
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_kinds = class, struct, interface, enum
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_method_should_be_camel_case.applicable_kinds = method
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_method_should_be_camel_case.applicable_accessibilities = private

dotnet_naming_rule.private_method_should_be_camel_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.private_method_should_be_camel_case.symbols = method
dotnet_naming_rule.private_method_should_be_camel_case.style = camel_case

dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_kinds = property, event, method
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_prefix = I
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.capitalization = camel_case

[*.cs]
csharp_indent_case_contents = true
csharp_indent_switch_labels = true

csharp_new_line_before_catch = false
csharp_new_line_before_else = false
csharp_new_line_before_finally = false
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = true
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
csharp_new_line_between_query_expression_clauses = true

csharp_indent_block_contents = true
csharp_indent_braces = false
csharp_indent_case_contents = true
csharp_indent_case_contents_when_block = true
csharp_indent_labels = one_less_than_current
csharp_indent_switch_labels = true

csharp_space_after_cast = false
csharp_space_after_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_after_comma = true
csharp_space_after_dot = false
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements = true
csharp_space_after_semicolon_in_for_statement = true
csharp_space_around_binary_operators = before_and_after
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = false
csharp_space_before_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_before_comma = false
csharp_space_before_dot = false
csharp_space_before_open_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_before_semicolon_in_for_statement = false
csharp_space_between_empty_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_name_and_opening_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_name_and_open_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_square_brackets = false

csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true
csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = true

csharp_prefer_braces = true:warning

csharp_style_expression_bodied_constructors = true:suggestion
csharp_style_expression_bodied_methods = true:suggestion
csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties = true:suggestion

csharp_style_inlined_variable_declaration = true:suggestion

csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_tuple_names = true:suggestion

csharp_style_var_elsewhere = true:suggestion
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types = true:suggestion
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent = true:suggestion

csharp_style_pattern_local_over_anonymous_function = true:suggestion

csharp_preferred_modifier_order = internal,protected,public,private,static,readonly,abstract,override,sealed,virtual:suggestion

csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_as_with_null_check = true:suggestion

[*.vb]
visual_basic_preferred_modifier_order = partial,default,private,protected,public,friend,notoverridable,overridable,mustoverride,overloads,overrides,mustinherit,notinheritable,static,shared,shadows,readonly,writeonly,dim,const,withevents,widening,narrowing,custom,async,iterator:silent
visual_basic_style_unused_value_assignment_preference = unused_local_variable:suggestion
visual_basic_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = unused_local_variable:silent
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule I am trying to define -- `private_method_should_be_camel_case` -- is in conflict with the `non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case` rule, whose symbol set (`.symbols = non_field_members`) includes non-public methods:

```
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
```

Removing the `private` accessibility from the `non_field_members` symbol set allows my new rule to be applied.

Answer (score 4):

So...there are a few different ways to go about this...I will recreate what worked for me.
Its basically in three parts:

**Part 1**
First: Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style->Formatting->Naming
Click the button at the bottom `Manage naming styles`
Click the green + to add a new one
Give it a Naming Style Title: i.e. camelCase
Under Capitalization select `camel Case Name`
[image: Options Image]
Click OK
Click OK

**Under Specification Select Private Method**

[image]

> Add a new Nameing Rule (green +)
> Change `Specification` to `Private Method`
> Change `Required Style` for `Private Method` to the camelCase
> ( the style you just created above)

Click OK

Up to now all we've done is just change the global was VS works.
(and again...there may be a better way...but this is what I did)

**Part 2**
First: Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style->General
Click button at the top `Generate .editorconfig file from settings`
[image: Generate .editorconfig]

You may see this dialog box at the top
[image: dialogebox]

So now you will have a custom .editorconfig in a folder called Solution Items
And also...now you will get warnings If you use PascalCase!!!
[image: warning]

**Part 3**

Undo the global effect created in part 1
First: Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style->Formatting->Naming
For `Non-Field Members` Change the `Required Style` back to `Pascal Case` (if this is what you want)
Click OK
Click OK

```
# Remove the line below if you want to inherit .editorconfig settings from higher directories
root = true

# C# files
[*.cs]

#### Core EditorConfig Options ####

# Indentation and spacing
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
tab_width = 4

# New line preferences
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = false

#### .NET Coding Conventions ####

# Organize usings
dotnet_separate_import_directive_groups = false
dotnet_sort_system_directives_first = false
file_header_template = unset

# this. and Me. preferences
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:silent
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:silent
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false:silent
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:silent

# Language keywords vs BCL types preferences
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true:silent
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true:silent

# Parentheses preferences
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_arithmetic_binary_operators = always_for_clarity:silent
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_binary_operators = always_for_clarity:silent
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_operators = never_if_unnecessary:silent
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_relational_binary_operators = always_for_clarity:silent

# Modifier preferences
dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers = for_non_interface_members:silent

# Expression-level preferences
dotnet_style_coalesce_expression = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_collection_initializer = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_explicit_tuple_names = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_null_propagation = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_object_initializer = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_operator_placement_when_wrapping = beginning_of_line
dotnet_style_prefer_auto_properties = true:silent
dotnet_style_prefer_compound_assignment = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_assignment = true:silent
dotnet_style_prefer_conditional_expression_over_return = true:silent
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_anonymous_type_member_names = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_inferred_tuple_names = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_is_null_check_over_reference_equality_method = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_boolean_expressions = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_prefer_simplified_interpolation = true:suggestion

# Field preferences
dotnet_style_readonly_field = true:suggestion

# Parameter preferences
dotnet_code_quality_unused_parameters = all:suggestion

#### C# Coding Conventions ####

# var preferences
csharp_style_var_elsewhere = false:silent
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types = false:silent
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent = false:silent

# Expression-bodied members
csharp_style_expression_bodied_accessors = true:silent
csharp_style_expression_bodied_constructors = false:silent
csharp_style_expression_bodied_indexers = true:silent
csharp_style_expression_bodied_lambdas = true:silent
csharp_style_expression_bodied_local_functions = false:silent
csharp_style_expression_bodied_methods = false:silent
csharp_style_expression_bodied_operators = false:silent
csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties = true:silent

# Pattern matching preferences
csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_as_with_null_check = true:suggestion
csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_is_with_cast_check = true:suggestion
csharp_style_prefer_switch_expression = true:suggestion

# Null-checking preferences
csharp_style_conditional_delegate_call = true:suggestion

# Modifier preferences
csharp_prefer_static_local_function = true:suggestion
csharp_preferred_modifier_order = public,private,protected,internal,static,extern,new,virtual,abstract,sealed,override,readonly,unsafe,volatile,async:silent

# Code-block preferences
csharp_prefer_braces = true:silent
csharp_prefer_simple_using_statement = true:suggestion

# Expression-level preferences
csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression = true:suggestion
csharp_style_deconstructed_variable_declaration = true:suggestion
csharp_style_inlined_variable_declaration = true:suggestion
csharp_style_pattern_local_over_anonymous_function = true:suggestion
csharp_style_prefer_index_operator = true:suggestion
csharp_style_prefer_range_operator = true:suggestion
csharp_style_throw_expression = true:suggestion
csharp_style_unused_value_assignment_preference = discard_variable:suggestion
csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = discard_variable:silent

# 'using' directive preferences
csharp_using_directive_placement = outside_namespace:silent

#### C# Formatting Rules ####

# New line preferences
csharp_new_line_before_catch = true
csharp_new_line_before_else = true
csharp_new_line_before_finally = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = true
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = all
csharp_new_line_between_query_expression_clauses = true

# Indentation preferences
csharp_indent_block_contents = true
csharp_indent_braces = false
csharp_indent_case_contents = true
csharp_indent_case_contents_when_block = true
csharp_indent_labels = one_less_than_current
csharp_indent_switch_labels = true

# Space preferences
csharp_space_after_cast = false
csharp_space_after_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_after_comma = true
csharp_space_after_dot = false
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements = true
csharp_space_after_semicolon_in_for_statement = true
csharp_space_around_binary_operators = before_and_after
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = false
csharp_space_before_colon_in_inheritance_clause = true
csharp_space_before_comma = false
csharp_space_before_dot = false
csharp_space_before_open_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_before_semicolon_in_for_statement = false
csharp_space_between_empty_square_brackets = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_name_and_opening_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_name_and_open_parenthesis = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_square_brackets = false

# Wrapping preferences
csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true
csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = true

#### Naming styles ####

# Naming rules

dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.symbols = interface
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.style = begins_with_i

dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = types
dotnet_naming_rule.types_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = non_field_members
dotnet_naming_rule.non_field_members_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_rule.private_method_should_be_camelcase.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.private_method_should_be_camelcase.symbols = private_method
dotnet_naming_rule.private_method_should_be_camelcase.style = camelcase

# Symbol specifications

dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_kinds = interface
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_method.applicable_kinds = method
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_method.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_method.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_kinds = class, struct, interface, enum
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.types.required_modifiers = 

dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_kinds = property, event, method
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, private, protected, protected_internal, private_protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_field_members.required_modifiers = 

# Naming styles

dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_prefix = I
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.begins_with_i.capitalization = pascal_case

dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.camelcase.capitalization = camel_case
```

Comment: My question was specifically about private methods; public methods should be Pascal case.