# VisualStudio: Set primary constructor parameters in camelCase (IDE1006 naming rule violation)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm getting an IDE1006 naming rule violation because the parameters in my primary constructor are written in lower case:

```
public class TestClass(int day){
   public int Day = day;
}
```

The [Captialization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) state that:

> The camelCasing convention, used only for parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word except the first word, as shown in the following examples. As the example also shows, two-letter acronyms that begin a camel-cased identifier are both lowercase.

> [...]

> ✔️ DO use PascalCasing for all public member, type, and namespace names consisting of multiple words.

> ✔️ DO use camelCasing for parameter names.

If I write is as an ordinary constructor, i.e.

```
public class TestClass{
   public int Day;

   public TestClass(int day){
      Day = day;
   }
}
```

the notification disappears (but I get another notification that tells me to use the primary constructor).

I tried to change the code styles via Tools->Options->C#

[image]

[image]

[image]

But the message prevails. How can I tell VS that a primary constructor's parameters should be written in camel case? I'm using the latest version.

Comment: If you think this is wrong, you can report it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues). There's an old [suggestion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48310), but it's about record.

Comment: can you just supress the issue in editorconfig?

Comment: @kir.gera I wouldn't know how to suppress it just for primary constructors. I'd like to keep it enabled for the other cases.

Comment: Close and re-open the solution to make the setting change effective.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856186/how-to-get-rid-of-naming-rule-violation-messages-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you said at the end about `message prevails`

I followed your steps to reproduce it. You can realize that the parameters of the main constructor should be in camel case.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's just that I need to reopen Visual Studio or enter other methods to make the suggestion take effect.

[image]

In addition, you should not use `day` for testing, because `day` itself conforms to `camelCasing`. You can try using `Day`

If my understanding is wrong, please tell me

Also I found a post that might be useful to you: [Set naming style to camelCase for private methods via .editorconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739680/set-naming-style-to-camelcase-for-private-methods-via-editorconfig)